# How to have one button do both "enable" and "disable" in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to ASP.Net MVC, and still trying to wrap my head around the controller and passing data to the view and back.

Here is my question. I have a model in my view with a property that is "isEnabled", which can be true or false.

I have an edit button, and an enable/disable button. Edit just takes me to a new view with a form.

I want the enable/disable button to change the property of the model to enabled or disabled.

Right now I have two separate buttons. When I click on them, it fires the appropriate action from the controller (EnableModel, DisableModel), and just reloads the current view.

How can I make it so, if the model is disabled the button shows and fires the enable action, and when it is enabled, the button shows and fires the disable action.

So here are the options I thought of.
1. Two buttons, I hide them as needed. I can use an if statement to check if the model is showing or not in razor.
2. Use javascript two to the above
3. Use javascript to physically change the button

What would be the best method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so looking back can't believe I ever even asked this haha.

I went the javascript route. I had a single button, and a simple onClick javascript class that would handle the toggling.